# WebAssembly error: memories may not be shared

Tags: webassembly

Im trying to figure out how to declare a shared memory import in WAT. I couldn't really find anything about it, but I came up with this:

```
(import "js" "memory" (memory 1 1 shared))
```

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to compile this with wat2wasm:

`test.wat:2:4: error: memories may not be shared`

So far, I didn't find any useful information about this error. Does this mean that my WASM compiler doesn't support shared memories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, I just figured out that `--enable-threads` needs to be enabled to make shared memories work.

Comment: I have the same problem and can't get your solution to work.  Here is testshm.wat (and it doesn't help to make this an import):

(module (memory 1 shared))

Now using the npm version of wat2wasm:
$ wat2wasm testshm.wat --enable-threads
...

Error: validate failed:
testshm.wat:1:10: error: memories may not be shared
(module (memory 1 shared))
         ^^^^^^
Has there been a change to wat2wasm?  How do you get it to assemble?

Comment: @JohnO'D I got a different error when I tried to compile your code, it said: "shared memories must have max sizes". - It's probably because you only specified the initial size. Try it in [wat2wasm sandbox](https://webassembly.github.io/wabt/demo/wat2wasm/) with `(module (memory 1 1 shared))`, just don't forget to tick the threads checkbox.

Comment: I had already tried (memory 3 3 shared) and it gives the same error.   It does work in the sandbox (with threads checked), but not with the wat2wasm command with the --enable-threads flag:  $ wat2wasm testshm.wat --enable-threads   Possibly my installation of wat2wasm is broken (it's installed via npm).  Is there any documentation of wat2wasm beyond wat2wasm --help?   -- Thanks!

Comment: @JohnO'D It's possible that you have an older version. [This](https://webassembly.github.io/wabt/doc/wat2wasm.1.html) the only documentation that I know of, but it's pretty much the same as `--help`

Comment: I just reinstalled wat2wasm 10 minutes ago via npm install; it's   v1.0.36, and it gives the same error.  Are you using the cmake version of wat2wasm or the npm version?  Possibly the npm build of wat2wasm is buggy, or maybe there is some other undocumented flag or environment setting that's required.

Comment: @JohnO'D Yes, I'm using the original wat2wasm, the one which is on npm is a clone. I just checked it's [repository](https://github.com/emilbayes/wat2wasm) on GitHub, and it looks like that it has a slightly different API, try `--features threads` instead of `--enable-threads`.

Comment: Problem solved.  It turns out that there are several versions of wat2wasm avaiilable via npm install.  The one to use is:  npm install -g wabt --- this installs a number of programs, including a version of wat2wasm that works; it is v1.0.23.  This behaves the same as your version: it requires the maximum memory size to be defined, and it allows shared memory.  Thanks very much for your help!  -- John